# MATLAB: How to apply a vectorized function using sparsity structure?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I need to (repeatedly) build a vector of length 200 from a vector of length 2500. I can describe this operation using multiplication by a matrix which is extremely sparse: it is 200x2500 and has only one entry in each row. But I have very little control over where this entry is. My actual problem is that I need to apply this matrix not to the vector that I currently have, but rather to some componentwise function of this vector. Since I have all this sparsity, it is wasteful to apply this componentwise function to all 2500 components of my vector. Instead I would rather apply it only to the 200 components that actually contribute.

A program (with randomly chosen numbers replacing of my actual numbers) which would have a similar problem would be something like this:

```
ind=randi(2500,200,1);
coefficients=randn(200,1);
A=sparse(1:200,ind,coefficients,200,2500);
x=randn(2500,1);
y=A*subplus(x);
```

What I don't like here is applying subplus to all of x; I would rather only have to apply it to x(ind), since only that contributes to the matrix product.

Right now the only way I can see to work around this is to replace my sparse matrix with a 200-component vector of coefficients and a 200-component vector of indices. Working this way, the code above would become:

```
ind=randi(2500,200,1);
coefficients=randn(200,1);
x=randn(2500,1);
y=coefficients.*subplus(x(ind))
```

Is there a better way to do this, preferably one that would work when A contains a few elements per row instead of just one?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can see what is going on in your code.

Comment: @Adriaan I gave it a shot. Is it OK?

Comment: IIRC, when performing matrix-vector multiplication with sparse matrices in MATLAB, it only uses the non-zero coefficients when calculating this operation under the hood... so there's nothing "wasteful" about it.  In fact, that is the whole point of using sparse matrices... apart from the memory savings that you would have compared to using dense matrices.  Did you try timing your application and seeing how long it takes?

Comment: @rayryeng The problem is that it will compute subplus(x) before it knows that most of the entries of subplus(x) are not actually required. Written as I wrote above, just calling subplus consumes about 10% of the time in my application.

Comment: I am unable to run your first code sample (`Error using sparse
Vectors must be the same lengths.`). How does `subplus` look like?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I forgot to put in some 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question throws an exception, I think it should be:

```
n=2500;
m=200;
ind=randi(n,m,1);
coefficients=randn(m,1);
A=sparse(1:m,ind,coefficients,m,n);
x=randn(n,1);
```

Your idea using `x(ind)` was basically right, but ind would reorder `x` which is not intended. Instead you could use `sort(unique(ind))`. I opted to use the sparse logical index `any(A~=0)` because I expect it to be faster, but you could compare both versions.

```
%original code
y=A*subplus(x);
```

.

```
%multiplication using sparse logical indexing:
relevant=any(A~=0);
y=A(:,relevant)*subplus(x(relevant));
```

.

```
%fixed version of your code
relevant=sort(unique(ind));
y=A(:,relevant)*subplus(x(relevant));
```

Comment: `unique` has the `'sorted'` argument built-in as well.

Comment: @Adriaan: The behaviour of `unique` was changed with `R2013a` and I don't fully remember the changes, just wanted to make sure it runs on all versions. For recent versions `relevant=unique(ind);` can be used.

Comment: Hi @lan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.